# Should I use localhost in the endpoint address of a WCF service?

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis

If I host a publicly available WCF web service in IIS, how should I configure the endpoint address? I think I can use either:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/MyService" ... />
```

or

```
<endpoint address="http://example.com/MyService" ... />
```

In both cases, a client on another machine must use the second option for its client binding.

If I use Visual Studio to create the client, both server bindings seem to work fine. However, I think I had trouble using  new-webserviceproxy in Powershell with the first option.

Does it matter which one I use on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN: Specifying an Endpoint Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749(v=vs.110).aspx):

> you must use **relative endpoint addresses for IIS-hosted service endpoints**. Supplying a fully-qualified endpoint address can lead to errors in the deployment of the service. For more information, see [Deploying an Internet Information Services-Hosted WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx).

From that link:

> When hosted **in IIS, endpoint addresses are always considered to be relative to the address of the .svc file** that represents the service. For example, if the base address of a WCF service is `http://localhost/Application1/MyService.svc` with the following endpoint configuration.
>
> ```
> <endpoint address="anotherEndpoint" .../>
> ```
>
> This provides an endpoint that can be reached at `http://localhost/Application1/MyService.svc/anotherEndpoint`

Comment: That's a very good point I missed in the documentation. I was using the configuration of a self-hosted service as my starting point. I wish WCF would throw an error if an absolute URL is used in IIS.